# Unable to display local image icon on Google Maps with rails helpers image_tag or image_path

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I'm setting a marker icon picture on my google maps and it works perfectly when I pass in an url, but when I set an image_tag that links to a local asset, it finds the asset but does not display it on the map. Here is my code:

`@home.marker(view_context.image_path("i-home.png", size: '80x80', class: 'text-size'))`

the helper gives me the following path

`"/assets/i-home-afcc4167c5d6c4a0bffbe87848bb9694437b7f506c3fb5465fe597642d6a41f2.png"`

I am also wondering why it doesn't work without the 'view_context', which used to work before.

I have even tried to add css attributes as well :

```
.text-size {
  width: 80px !important;
  height: 80px !important;
}
```

Here is the code with url that works :

```
@home.marker("http://res.cloudinary.com/dndagbvyi/image/upload/c_scale,w_80/v1490692341/dog-shadow-02_m1vpet.png")
```

And the 'marker' method :

```
    def marker(image)
      Gmaps4rails.build_markers(self) do |address, marker|
      marker.lat address.latitude
      marker.lng address.longitude
      marker.infowindow address.name
      marker.picture({
                  anchor: [40, 58],
                  url: image,
                  width: 500,
                  height: 500,
                 })
     end
   end
```

Comment: Please show the code that works with url

Answer (score 0):

Try using single parameter to image_path method.

```
@home.marker(view_context.image_path("i-home.png"))
```